# Google Maps API JS: Show map of a certain town

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

Isn't it any longer possible in Google Maps API V3 (JavaScript) to display a marker at a setted/given town name? This is my code:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('locate'), myOptions);
```

There is the line `center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)` but I haven't the LatLng-Coordinates; just the town name. How could I display now the marker based on the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options... First, you can use the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/), which allows you to find the Lat/Lng of a site on the fly. Second, you can [use this method](http://www.amitpatil.me/find-city-on-maps-api-tutorial/), which requires a database.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with a limited set of towns, I'd suggest you create your own DB or hashmap of town names to latlng coordinates.  Otherwise use either of Chris's suggestions.